# CRON (no tty): Delete message with specific "Message-Id"

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, email, mutt

I have a situation where I need to delete from mailbox (eg. **/var/mail/root**) messages with specific **Message-Id**.

Following code works only from console, but I have to do it without user interaction running from cron /etc/crontab.

> **File:** /tmp/clear_spam_test

```
mutt -f /var/mail/root -e "set alias_file=/var/mail/root" -e "set crypt_use_gpgme=no" -e "push <delete-pattern>~iSomeMessageId@messageid.test\n<sync-mailbox>qy"
```

I tried many variations

1. `ssh -tt localhost 'bash -s' < /tmp/clear_spam_test`

> **Output:**
>   `mutt -f /var/mail/root -e "set alias_file=/var/mail/root" -e "set crypt_use_gpgme=no" -e "push <delete-pattern\>~iSomeMessageId@messageid.test\n\<sync-mailbox\>qy"`
>
> echo -e "\nTEST $( whoami ) $0"
>      exit 0
>      `<n>~iSomeMessageId@messageid.test\n<sync-mailbox>qy"`
>      Error opening terminal: unknown.
>      TEST root bash
>      exit
>     Connection to localhost closed.

2. `ssh -t localhost 'bash -s' < /tmp/clear_spam_test`

> **Output:**
>   Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>   No recipients were specified.

3. `ssh -T localhost 'bash -s' < /tmp/clear_spam_test`

> **Output:**
>   No recipients were specified.

4. `ssh -tt $server <<'ENDSSH'
   echo $(/tmp/clear_spam_test)
   exit 0
   ENDSSH`

> **Output:**
>     Error opening terminal: unknown.
>     TEST root /tmp/clear_spam_test
>     logout
>     Connection to localhost closed.

5. `ssh -t $server <<'ENDSSH'
   echo $(/tmp/clear_spam_test)
   exit 0
   ENDSSH`

> **Output:**
>     Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>     mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>     No recipients were specified.
>     TEST root /tmp/clear_spam_test

6. `ssh -T $server <<'ENDSSH'
   echo $(/tmp/clear_spam_test)
   exit 0
   ENDSSH`

> **Output:**
>     mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>     No recipients were specified.
>     TEST root /tmp/clear_spam_test

None of it works. I also tried IFS.

Comment: I still have`t figured it out. Any clue?

Comment: Is it fair game to shut down the local MTA while the delete operation occurs? Then the `/var/mail/root` file could be backed up for safety, and edited directly via a script. [See the man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=formail) for `formail`, a component of the `procmail` family, and note the `-D maxlen idcache` command-line switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here. This mutt command seems to depend on a working terminal window that cron cannot build.
At least for me it helped to start a virtual terminal using screen:

```
screen -d -m  mutt -f /var/mail/root -e "set alias_file=/var/mail/root" -e "set crypt_use_gpgme=no" -e "push <delete-pattern>~iSomeMessageId@messageid.test\n<sync-mailbox>qy"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The  screen command did the work.

I only had to change the line to: 
screen -d -m  mutt -f /var/mail/root -e "set alias_file=/var/mail/root" -e "set crypt_use_gpgme=no" -e "push ** D**~iSomeMessageId@messageid.test\n<sync-mailbox>qy**qy**"

and add another **qy** to the end, so it does properly closes the mutt.

Comment: The **D~i** option deletes only message with matching pattern.